# How to make one dictionary inside another one and that inside an another dictionary on python

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

```
cars= {"italy": Lamborghini,"germany":["Benz","BMW"],"korea":{"north korea":"none","south korea":{"kia", "hyundai":["creta","santafe"]}}}
```

Why couldn't I print the contents on Hyundai? Kindly please help

```
print(cars[korea][south korea][hyundai]
```

Comment: You have syntax errors in your dictionary definition (missing quotes around `Lamborghini` no value for `kia`, etc) . If you fix those you can get the values with `cars['korea']['south korea']['hyundai']`. <-- the quotes matter.

Comment: `{"kia", "hyundai":["creta","santafe"]}` is not a dictionary because `"kia"` is not in the format of `key: value,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all assign a value to every key.`kia does not have any value` Then pass keys as string.

```
cars= {"italy": "Lamborghini","germany":["Benz","BMW"],"korea":{"north korea":"none","south korea":{"kia":None, "hyundai":["creta","santafe"]}}}

print(cars["korea"]["south korea"]["hyundai"])
```